# Table referencing itself , MySQL, primary key and foreign key in same table , select statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

how i select column of categories wich two types `SubCat` & `MainCat` from Table referencing itself called `cat`:

where FOREIGN KEY (`maincat_id`) REFERENCES at (`cat_id`) which is PrimeryKey

table in DataBase:

```
cat_id    catname       maincat_id   cat_type
1         hello         NULL         1     
2         one           3            2
3         test          1            2
4         te3           3            2
```

As you see if `cat_type=1` so it's `SubCat`.

i just need table select all the `SubCat` and the `MainCat` which it's belong, as this:

```
 catname       Root_name
 one           test        
 test          hello          
 te3           test
```

more info:
We have One table of categories called 'cat', in it There are (Main Categories) and (Sub Categories), which make small tree (just one level depth) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a simple inner join for this:

```
SELECT t1.catname AS Category, t2.catname AS Subcategory 
FROM cat t1 INNER JOIN cat t2
ON t1.cat_id = t2.maincat_id
WHERE t1.cat_type = 1
```

After all, i hope i understand your question right, and this is what you need.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94e65/18

Comment: what is {your SubCat} ? {your MainCat} ?

Comment: Its your database tables, the name on them

Comment: if its only 1 table, i dont understand the setup on your database.. :-(

Comment: There r a lot of tables, but here we have the table of categories called 'cat', There are (Main Categories) and (Sub Categories), make small tree (just one level depth) . 
rest the information u have in the question :)

Comment: @Imad.M try the query as it is now. and check out the fiddle. You shouldn't be expecting people to totally solve your problem on SO...

Answer (score 0):

you can use self join for this

```
select c.catname as catname ,m.catname as  Root_name from cat as c, cat as m
where c.maincat_id = m.cat_id &&  c.cat_type=2;
```

Comment: i said my table name is (cat) . so i just put it in , and not works, gave me :#1054 - Unknown column 'c.catname' in 'field list'

Comment: select c.catname , m.catname from cat as c, cat as m
where c.maincat_id = m.cat_id &&  c.cat_type=2;